# Grails gorm-mongodb embedded objects

Tags: grails, mongodb, groovy, gorm-mongodb

I have two mapped classes: `BaseClass` and `ConcreteClass extends BaseClass`, both are stored into **same collections**.

Base class have an field, stored as embedded value - object with class `Dimensions`, that is configured as embedded by:

```
class BaseClass {
    Dimensions dimensions

    static embedded = ['dimensions']
}
```

btw, when i'm trying to load it by `BaseClass.get(id)` it fails with `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'my.package.Dimensions' is defined`

and, also, same problem when this class, with embedded field, becomes an embedded value inside an another object. I mean:

```
class OtherClass {
   BaseClass baseClass

   static embedded = ['baseClass']
}
```

How to configure those embedded objects/fields?

As MongoDB is a document-oriented storage, it's very commons situation to have deep objects structures for a stored document. But I can't figure out how it can be done with gorm-mongodb plugin

Comment: You've got a spelling error.  The first time, its spelled `dimesions`, and the second time its spelled `dimensions`.  Did you type that in, or is that copied from your code?

Comment: Can you provide some information about the Dimensions class? Is it a grails domain class, and what does its definition look like?